# How to access function environment variable in nested problems?

Tags: r, function, plyr

I have been developing some functions for dose response analysis in R that make use of the `uniroot.all()`function.  Say I have a function such as:

```
library(rootSolve)
library(plyr)

examplefunction <- function(x){

  adply(mtcars, 1, summarize,
    solution <- uniroot(function (a){
      mpg + x + a},
      interval = c(-100,100)))

}
```

If I enter `examplefunction(1)`, I receive the error

`Error in f(lower, ...) : object 'x' not found`

Now my function has several other variables and fitting equations, and the function is solved using `optim()`, but I hope this is explains the issue sufficiently.

Currently I have "solved" my problem by assigning my variables globally in the beginning of the function like this:

```
library(rootSolve)
library(plyr)

examplefunction <- function(x){

x2 <<- x
  adply(mtcars, 1, summarize,
    solution <- uniroot(function (a){
      mpg + x2 + a},
      interval = c(-100,100)))

}
```

This is pretty sloppy in my opinion.  What I would like to do is to allow `uniroot.all()` to access `x` from the function environment rather than the global environment.

`x` is used in parts of the function outside of `adply()` and the whole function is ran with `optim()` so I can't just define them inside the `uniroot.all()` or `adply()` functions.

Thanks for any help.